# Using older libraries with new Reference Counting in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, reference-counting

The latest version of XCode supports reference counting.  However many older libraries are not compatible with the new Reference Counting architecture.

Is there a Compiler option or something to use non Reference Counted libraries with a new reference counted app, or do I always have to update the code?

What happens with libraries that use C (obviously not reference counted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. In the `build phases` tab for the target you want to change, you can set compiler flags for each file in your project under the `Compile Sources` section.

Simply set the compiler flags for the files you don't want to use `ARC` on to:

```
fno-objc-arc
```

[image: disable ARC example]

You can hold `Cmd` while selecting files to add the flag to several files at once.